# xtrace equivalent in the fish shell

Tags: debugging, fish

Is there an equivalent of POSIX shells' `set -x` or `set -o xtrace` that cause the shell to display the commands being run in the `fish` shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since fish 3.1.0, the `fish_trace` variable makes this functionality available:

```
> set fish_trace on; isatty; set -e fish_trace
++ source share/fish/functions/isatty.fish
++++ function isatty -d 'Tests if a file descriptor is a tty'
+ isatty
+++ set -l options h/help
+++ argparse -n isatty h/help --
+++ if
+++ set -q _flag_help
+++ end if
+++ if
+++ set -q 'argv[2]'
+++ end if
+++ set -l fd
++++ set fd 0
+++ '[' -t 0 ']'
+ set -e fish_trace
```

The location of the trace output is controlled by the `--debug-output` option to the fish process.

Before fish 3.1.0, you can use `fish -p some_trace_file` to run a fish session which outputs a profile to "some_trace_file", which can achieve almost the same effect (with some disadvantages - see the comments below).

Comment: Thanks. That's useful indeed. The output is more readily usable than with `-d4`, and it gives that useful timing information and function call depth. One has to wait until the shell exits (and not die of a signal) though to get any of that output.

Answer (score 5):

The closest thing I can see, similar to `set -o xtrace` in `zsh`, by calling `fish` with `-d 4` or `--debug-level=4`:

```
$ fish -d 4 -c 'echo 1'
fish: Exec job 'builtin source /usr/share/fish/config.fish 2>/dev/null' with id 1
fish: Exec job 'set -g IFS \n\ \t' with id 2
fish: Set status of set -g IFS \n\ \t to 0 using short circuit
fish: Job is constructed
fish: Continue job 2, gid 0 (set -g IFS \n\ \t), COMPLETED, NON-INTERACTIVE
...
fish: Exec job 'echo 1' with id 1
1
fish: Set status of echo 1 to 0 using short circuit
fish: Job is constructed
fish: Continue job 1, gid 0 (echo 1), COMPLETED, NON-INTERACTIVE
```

Comment: Thanks. Those `Set status of` are only output for builtins though. You get more interesting output with `-d4`  (and piping to `grep '^fish: Exec job'` for instance)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: yeah, of course, `-d4` make it more similar to `xtrace`.